# Can't seem to pass RDS Database instance metrics to another stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have 2 stacks, one where I create an RDS DB and another meant for cloudwatch alarms. I'm trying to pass the dbInstance details from here:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as rds from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import * as cloudwatch from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudwatch';
import { StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { IMetric } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudwatch';


export class DatabaseStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly dbName: rds.DatabaseInstance
    public readonly dbCPUUsage: IMetric
    public readonly dbInstance: any;
    constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

/*Created a VPC with a PUBLIC and an ISOLATED subnet groups.
RDS instance will be launched in an ISOLATED subnet because we'll be 
connecting to it from our EC2 instance, which is in the same VPC.*/
        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'my-cdk-vpc',{
            ...
        });
        const ec2InstanceSG = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'ec2-instance-sg', {
            vpc,
        });

/*create security group for the EC2 instance with single inbound rule,
which allows SSH connections from anywhere.*/
        ec2InstanceSG.addIngressRule(
            ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
            ec2.Port.tcp(22),
            'allow SSH connections from anywhere',
        );

//Created a t2.micro EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2 AMI and placed it in a PUBLIC subnet.

        const ec2Instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'ec2-instance', {
            ...
        });

/*Create RDS instance*/
    const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'db-instance',{
            ...

    });

//allow connections to our RDS instance, on port 5432, from the security group of the EC2 instance
    dbInstance.connections.allowFrom(ec2Instance, ec2.Port.tcp(5432));
    
//database hostname that we'll use to connect to our RDS instance
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'dbEndpoint', {
        value:dbInstance.instanceEndpoint.hostname,
    });

//name of the secret that stores the password of the postgres user
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'secretName', {
        value: dbInstance.secret?.secretName!,
    });

    new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'HighCPU', {
        metric: dbInstance.metricCPUUtilization(),
        threshold: 100,
        evaluationPeriods: 2,
    })
    
    this.dbName = dbInstance;
    this.dbCPUUsage = dbInstance.metricCPUUtilization();
    }
    ;
    }

    export interface CloudwatchStackProps extends StackProps {
        dbNameExport: rds.IDatabaseInstance;
        dbCPUUsageExport: IMetric;
     };
```

To this stack:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as cloudwatch from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudwatch';
import { IDatabaseInstance } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { CloudwatchStackProps } from '../lib/cdk-database-stack';

export class CloudwatchStack extends Stack {
  private readonly dbInstance: IDatabaseInstance
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: CloudwatchStackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);
      const cpuUsage = props.dbCPUUsageExport

      new cloudwatch.Alarm(this.dbInstance, 'CPUUsage', {
        metric: cpuUsage(),
        threshold: 100,
        evaluationPeriods: 2,
       });

    }
  }
```

The error I get when doing CDK Diff is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metric'))".

bin file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { AmsAwsTestingGroundsStack } from '../lib/ams-aws-testing-grounds-stack';
import { CloudwatchStack } from '../lib/cdk-cloudwatch-stack';
import { DatabaseStack } from '../lib/cdk-database-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();

new AmsAwsTestingGroundsStack(app, 'AmsAwsTestingGroundsStack');

const databaseStack = new DatabaseStack(app, 'DatabaseStack');

const cloudwatchstack = new CloudwatchStack(app, 'CloudwatchStack', {
    dbNameExport: databaseStack.dbName,
    dbCPUUsageExport: databaseStack.dbCPUUsage,
});
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

**EDIT - solution**

```
new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'CPUUsage', { 
  metric: cpuUsage,
  threshold: 100,
  evaluationPeriods: 2,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with the `Alarm` constructor:

```js
new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'CPUUsage', { // <-- In a stack, `scope` should (almost) always be `this`
  metric: cpuUsage, // <-- not callable, remove the ()
  threshold: 100,
  evaluationPeriods: 2,
});
```

Comment: It worked! I tried removing the () before but never thought about the 'this' topic. Thank you so much!

I have a question though, will I always need to export an interface in order to access the properties of the DB in a different stack?

Comment: @Nelson  Technically speaking you can _export_ stack variables without an extended props interface.  The props interface is required for _importing_ into a stack.  Because `CloudwatchStackProps` describes the contract `CloudwatchStack` expects, move the props interface to `CloudwatchStack.ts`.  The interface definition typically does not need to be exported - IDEs like VSCode can apply type checking implicitly.